# Delete rows from Table 1 based on the rows in Table 2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
   Table 1
    Color
    ------
    Red
    Red
    Blue

    Table 2
    Color
    ------
    Red
    Blue

    Result
    Red (since red in Table 1 2x and only 1x in Table 2)
```

How can I design the TSQL to delete rows in Table 1 based on the rows in Table 2?

In other words, iterate Table 2 one time and for each color, delete one color from Table 1 (not all the colors that equal current color of Table 2).

Comment: IMO; You need to have a PK in your tables to do that ;).

Comment: Can u add more context to your problem. Because 
    `delete from table1
    where color in (select color from table2)` this will delete rows which are in table 2..

Comment: Is it possible that `Table2` has more than one row with the same `Color`? Your sample data doesn't cover many cases, it would help if you added more rows to it.

Answer (score 4):

Just number each color and delete all where number is greater then 1:

```
;with cte as(select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by t1.color
                            order by(select null)) as rn
             from table1 t1
             join table2 t2 on t1.color = t2.color)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Or change to:

```
delete from cte where rn = 1
```

if you want to delete only one row for each color.

Comment: Thanks for feedback...I was getting an error on "as rn)" so I moved right paren over nul)) but I'm not sure I'm getting correct behavior? See line 12 in SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3316

Comment: Yes you are right. There was a little bug. I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Table1 Table (color nvarchar(4))
INSERT INTO @Table1  Values ('Red')
INSERT INTO @Table1  Values ('Red')
INSERT INTO @Table1  Values ('Blue')

DECLARE @Table2 Table (color nvarchar(4))
INSERT INTO @Table2 Values ('Red')
INSERT INTO @Table2  Values ('Blue')

DELETE a
FROM (
SELECT t1.*,
    row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY t1.color ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
        ) AS rownum

FROM @Table1 t1
WHERE t1.color IN (
        SELECT t2.color
        FROM @Table2 t2
        )
) a
WHERE a.rownum =1
```

change to a.rownum>1 if you need to delete duplicate color

Comment: Hey @OP Does this work for you ? If so please do select it as an answer.